# When running 'rvm get head' I get: Unrecognized command line argument: 'get' ( see: 'rvm usage' )". How do I fix that?

Tags: rvm

As the title says, I ran `rvm get head` in an attempt to update RVM to the latest version.

The error message I got was: `Unrecognized command line argument: 'get' ( see: 'rvm usage' )`

How do I fix this ?

Running RVM on OS X - 10.6.7.

Answer (score 4):

```
rvm update --head
rvm reload
rvm get latest
```

from http://seanbehan.com/ruby/how-to-upgrade-rvm-on-mac-os-x/