# Why do I get an "Unrecognized command line argument" using "rvm use 1.9.2"? 

Tags: ruby, rvm

I'm trying to use `rvm` (the Ruby version manager) on a Mac Mini. However, when I try:

```
rvm install 1.9.2
```

I get `ERROR: Unrecognized command line argument: 'install 1.9.2' ( see: 'rvm usage' )`

When I try:

```
rvm use 1.9.2
```

I also get `ERROR: Unrecognized command line argument: 'use 1.9.2' ( see: 'rvm usage' )`

`rvm usage` works fine, though.

Anyone know what's wrong? I think I found a message in another forum that said my bash might be outdated, resulting in some regex being incorrectly parsed possibly, but `bash --version` says my bash version is `3.2.48(1)-release`, which is the same version as on my MacBook Pro, which can run `rvm` fine.

UPDATE: Solved (kind of) -- for some reason, my `/usr/local/bin/rvm` is at version 1.10.2 (the latest) and yet gives me all these errors. But if I switch to `.rvm/bin/rvm`, which is also at version 1.10.2, everything works fine... So bounty will be given to anyone who can explain why!

Comment: Have you tried this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6165719/when-running-rvm-get-head-i-get-unrecognized-command-line-argument-get-s

Comment: Doesn't work: the first two commands pass, but on `rvm get latest`, I get
`ERROR: Unrecognized command line argument: 'get latest' ( see: 'rvm usage' )`. (And the same errors on the commands I want to run.)

Comment: I use `rvm get head` which will take it to the latest version. Use `rvm help get` to make sure that command is available, and, if it is, `get head` will upgrade you to the latest version. Currently its at 1.10.1. After upgrading be sure to do a `rvm reload` in all shells open, or close and reopen the shells to pick up the latest version.

Comment: I have once encountered this errors on my Debian. The problem appeared after `rvm get latest` with a quite old version. Unfortunately the only solution that I came up with was to completely remove rvm and reinstall it from scratch.

Comment: Is there a `/etc/rvmrc` file? In that case, what are the contents? Is there a `/usr/local/rvm` directory? In that case, what are the contents of `/usr/local/rvm/scripts`?

Answer (score 2):

You might have a really old `rvm` installed. The best procedure is to re-install using the method on [the RVM page](https://rvm.io). It changes from time to time so I'm not pasting it here.

I've never seen any issues with `bash` as the OS usually has a reasonably up-to-date version and `rvm` runs on a variety of systems.

Answer (score 1):

You can try with this command first, before install Ruby in order to know if you meet installation requirements:

```
rvm --debug requirements ruby-1.9.2
```

After that you can run the install command:

```
rvm install 1.9.2
```

Quote my source: [RVM error with Requirements installation failed with status:1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17641230/3057986)