# RVM error with Requirements installation failed with status:1

Tags: ruby, linux, macos, command, rvm

I tried to install ruby 1.9.3 using command `rvm install 1.9.3 --with-gcc=clang`. But I got error saying

```
No binary rubies available for: osx/10.9/x86_64/ruby-1.9.3-p448.
Continuing with compilation.
Please read 'rvm help mount' to get more information on binary rubies.
Requirements installation failed with status: 1.
```

While I look into the installing log, I found it's saying

```
config/: Can't update time for config
doc/: Can't update time for doc
m4/: Can't update time for m4
Mk/: Can't update time for Mk
```

I tried many ways to install, but get the same error again and again, so what the problem is? And how should I do?

Comment: the error is only `Requirements installation failed with status: 1.` please run and show whole output of: `rvm --debug requrements ruby-1.9.3`

Comment: It still got an error. Error running 'requirements_osx_port_install_port',
please read /Users/hxssg1124/.rvm/log/1373851887_port_install.log
Requirements installation failed with status: 1.
__rvm_rm_rf already gone: /Users/hxssg1124/.rvm/tmp/50718*

Comment: please edit your whole post and include whole output from the command - it is hard to tell anything without it

Answer (score 2):

You're running this on Mavericks/10.9, a prerelease OS. RVM checks the OS version and then looks for ruby binary packages that match that specific OS version on the server. There aren't yet any such binary packages.

If you install [homebrew](http://brew.sh) first, RVM should be able to get a working 1.9.3 ruby from there.

Answer (score 0):

Bypass your macports:

Use  sudo mv /opt/local ~/macports

Then make sure your Xcode is current and that should work.